# Reading a file into an array in C

Tags: arrays, file

I would like to read a file called "input" with a lot of lines and 10 columns into an array using C. I wrote the following code:

```
FILE *file;

file=fopen("input","r");

i=0;

while ( fgetc(file) != EOF )
{
    fscanf(file,"%e\t%e",&x[i],&y[i]);
    i++;
}
```

The problem that I am ecoutering is that the first element of the file is not read. It is read however when the file contains an initial indent.

Could you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: fgetc reads a character from the file, that it why it works with indent. Try feof to check for end of file instead

Answer (score 0):

`fgetc()` reads a character and returns it and increments the `file pointer`. next when you call `fscanf()`, the first character won't be seen as its already past first character. If you want, only use `fscanf()` and check for `EOF` to detect end of file.